# BadMethodCallException with message 'Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::messages does not exist.'

Tags: laravel, vue.js, migration, faker, tinker

I am trying to make a chatbox using Laravel and Vue.js. I am following this online [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aTfMHg3V1Q&t=194s). I have followed almost every step to a tee and I cannot tell why I am not getting the desired result. Here is what I have done thus far:

I have created a User model and a Message model with the correct table columns and migrations. In the User model I established a hasMany relationship with the Message model. In the Message model, I established a belongsTo relationship with User.

When I go into tinker, I can do:

```
factory(App\User::class)->create()
```

just fine, like the guy in the tutorial can do. However when I try to do: 
`App\User::find(4)->messages()->created(['message'=> "Hello from Sharon"])`

I get this error:

```
BadMethodCallException with message 'Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::messages does not exist.'
```

Here is my code:

User Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password','api_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function messages()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Message::class);
    }
}
```

Message Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Message extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['message'];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
 }
```

Message Migration:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateMessagesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('messages', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->text('message');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('messages');
    }
}
```

If you could let me know what I am doing wrong, I would really appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Restart the php artisan tinker and re-run your code. It works:)

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are getting this error:

```
BadMethodCallException with message 'Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::created does not exist.'
```

To save models to relationships, use [`create`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#the-create-method) method, but not `created` method, for example:

```
App\User::find(4)->messages()->create(['message'=>'Hello from Sharon']);
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of `App\User::find(4)->messages()->created(['message'=> "Hello from Sharon"])`

try to use

```
App\User::find(4)->messages()->create(['message'=> "Hello from Sharon"])
```

or

```
App\User::find(4)->messages()->save(['message'=> "Hello from Sharon"])
```